# Does Swift.Combine Publishers.CombineLatest have a bug handling back pressure correctly? (demand from downstream)

Tags: swift, combine

I am seeing a very odd behavior in Publishers.CombineLatest related to demand management. In my code I have created a custom .withLatestFrom operator which manages backpressure by limiting upstream demand.

I am running in a situation where `Publishers.CombineLatest` propagates demand only to the 2nd publisher (latest2) but not to the first one (latest1).

What do you think? Is this a bug in CombineLatest - or do any of you see another reason why this might happen? I am not sure if miss anything, but to me it looks like quite a serious bug in a very common operator?

I am a bit puzzled - as this situation is currently stopping a publisher chain in my app...

Here is a test case (I have simplified it from my previous post and taken out any non-standard code):

```
func testCombineLatest() {
    
    let latest1 = PassthroughSubject<Int,Never>()
    let latest2 = PassthroughSubject<Int,Never>()
    
    var result:[[Int]] = []
    var subscription:Subscription?
    
    let subscriber = AnySubscriber<(Int,Int),Never>(
        receiveSubscription: {sub in
            subscription = sub
            sub.request(.max(1))
        },
        receiveValue: { (v1,v2) in
            result.append([v1,v2])
            return .max(1)
        },
        receiveCompletion: {_ in}
    )
    
    let publisher = Publishers.CombineLatest(latest1.print("Latest1"), latest2.print("Latest2"))
        .print("CombineLatest")
    
    publisher
        .subscribe(subscriber)
    
    latest1.send(1)
    latest2.send(1)
    latest1.send(2) //<- This has no effect.
    latest2.send(2)
    
    latest1.send(completion: .finished)
    latest2.send(completion: .finished)
    
    print("Result is:\(result)")
    
    XCTAssertEqual(result, [[1,1], [2,1], [2,2] ])

}
```

And here ist the output from the test run:

```
Test Case '-[CAPTests.CAPTestPublisherExtensions testCombineLatest]' started.
Latest1: receive subscription: (PassthroughSubject)
Latest2: receive subscription: (PassthroughSubject)
CombineLatest: receive subscription: (CombineLatest)
CombineLatest: request max: (1)
Latest1: request max: (1)
Latest2: request max: (1)
Latest1: receive value: (1)
Latest2: receive value: (1)
CombineLatest: receive value: ((1, 1))
CombineLatest: request max: (1) (synchronous)
Latest2: request max: (1) (synchronous)
Latest2: receive value: (2)
CombineLatest: receive value: ((1, 2))
CombineLatest: request max: (1) (synchronous)
Latest2: request max: (1) (synchronous)
Latest1: receive finished
Latest2: receive finished
CombineLatest: receive finished
Result is:[[1, 1], [1, 2]]
error: -[CAPTests.CAPTestPublisherExtensions testCombineLatest] : XCTAssertEqual failed: ("[[1, 1], [1, 2]]") is not equal to ("[[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2]]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple’s CombineLatest and Merge implementation does not deal with demand correctly. Here is my own implementation of Merge and CombineLatest operators that manages upstreams demand and downstream demand by another way. https://gist.github.com/nikislyak/d199ab1fe44ceec4eeaff8d4cdc1174b